# Merging different persistence unit

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, eclipselink

I'm developing a maven modular project with spring and vaadin that has the following structure

```
|-- parent
`-- pom.xml
    |-- model1
    |   `-- pom.xml
    |-- model2
         -- pom.xml
    |-- services
         -- pom.xml
    |-- web-app
         -- pom.xml
```

model1 and model2 are two maven-archetype-quickstart that I modified in this way

```
|-- model1
    |--src
        |--main
            |--java
        |--main
            |--resources
                |-- META-INF
                    -- persistence.xml

|-- model2
    |--src
        |--main
            |--java
        |--main
            |--resources
                |-- META-INF
                    -- persistence.xml
```

Moreover in the model2 pom I have this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>model1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

The persistence files are defined in the following way

Model1 persistence.xml

```
<persistence>
<persistence-unit name="model1Unit">

  <class>it.mycompany.User</class>
  <class>it.mycompany.UserDetail</class>
  <class>it.mycompany.Address</class>
  <class>it.mycompany.Agent</class>
  <class>it.mycompany.Agency</class>

  // and more others

</persistence-unit>
```

Model2 persistence.xml

```
persistence>
<persistence-unit name="model2Unit">

  <class>it.mycompany.Agreement</class>
  <class>it.mycompany.AgreementDetail</class>

  // and more others

</persistence-unit>
```

Now my trouble is that within the mapping of the model2 project I want to do the following thing:

```
    @Entity
    public class Agreement{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private Agent agent;

}
```

but the agent entity is contained in the model1 project/data source. Practically I want to use some entity of the model1 project in the model2 project to avoid of
recreate them.

Is this possible?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Entities (Tables) mapped in model1Unit and model2Unit belong to two different DBs?

Comment: Yes the tables belong to two different DBs

Comment: If Agreement and Agent belong to two different DBs then how logically/physically they are mapped to each other. How the relationship exist between them in DB? Basically I want to know what relationship exits between them as you are using @ManyToOne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using a [Composite Persistence Units](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Composite)

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing jar containing entities in Model2 persistence.xml without recreating them.

```
<jar-file>Model_1_Entity.jar</jar-file>
```